# array of string fill of data in jquery but go empty to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

the problem is i pass string array from jquery to controller and when i use debugger in browser see the array full of data but when i but brake point in function in mvc controller the parameter arrive = null

code in controller

```
 public ActionResult SendLocalMail(string Body, string From, string to, string subject, string[] attachments)
{
}
```

code in script

```
$("#btnSendMail").on("click", function () {
        debugger;
        var id = btun1.siblings(".user_id").val();
        var prev_attachment = $('#att a');
        if (prev_attachment.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < prev_attachment.length; i++) {
                paths.push(prev_attachment[i].title);
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Mail/SendLocalMail',
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { Body: $("#mailbody").val(), From: $("#SendFrom").val(), to: $("#tags").val(), subject: $("#Subject").val(), attachments: paths },
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is "arrive" in the code?

Comment: i mean `attachments` parameter arrive to the function equal null @epascarello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do this

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
traditional: true,
data: { /* your data */ }.
```

or

```
contentType: 'application/json',
traditional: false,
data: JSON.stringify({ /* your data */ },
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the meaning of this code i added "i take the second option you write"

Comment: @Radwa, [here](http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/) is a good explanation